# why can't Countdownlatch in java stops at given latch count?

Tags: java, countdownlatch

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class Processor implements Runnable {
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public Processor(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5); // coundown from 5 to 0

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); // 2 Threads in pool

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Processor(latch)); // ref to latch. each time call new Processes latch will count down by 1
        }

        try {
            latch.await();  // wait until latch counted down to 0
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed.");
    }

}
```

Output:

Started
Started
Started
Started
Started
Started
Started
Completed`
Started
Started
Started

In the above code "Completed" should be printed after 6 times "Started" as latch count downs to 5 - 0, why it is always 7th or 8th time? Have i understood wrong?

Comment: `new CountDownLatch(5); // coundown from 3 to 0` do you mean 5, or 3?

Comment: `main` starts ten of them, and they all print Started as soon as they start. There's no reason you shouldn't happen to see all ten before `main` ever gets to awaiting the latch, other than sheer luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread pool has size 2 and your `Processor` threads take 3 seconds to execute.

- First two `Processors` threads are started, the both print `Started` and they finish 3 seconds later.
- Then the next two are started and again they both print `Started` and finish 3 second later.
- Then another two (5th and 6th) are started, print `Started` and 3 seconds later when one of them (or both) finishes. At this point there are multiple things that are going to happen at roughly the same time (so the order is kind of random):

  1. The main thread resumes and prints `Completed`
  2. 7th `Processor` thread is started and prints `Started`
  3. 8th `Processor` thread is started and prints `Started`

Therefore, `Completed` is always going to be preceded by 6, 7 or 8 `Started` print outs.

Answer (score 0):

So, `CountDownLatch` does not guarantee that it will resume the parent thread (here I mean the thread from which you have called `latch.await();`) execution as soon as the Count Down goes to `0`. So, what happens when Count Down latch countdown to 0 that means now parent Thread can resume its work and that does not mean it will get the get the CPU then and there. So, it can resume that does not mean CPU schedule the parent thread as soon as the countdown to `0`. If there are other threads then is there is a possibility that those can execute before the parent thread. **In your case, it ensures that it will not execute `before` the `5` time printing `Started`** but it does `ensure` that it will be `exactly` after printing `5` times `Started`. You may also observe at a certain execution of your code `Completed` is printing at end of all `Started` printing.